# Struggling with a nested Expression Tree in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to create an Expression Tree in C# to dynamically represent the following nested lambda...

```
item => selectorList.Any(selector => terms.Any(sTerm => selector.Contains(sTerm))
```

Where:

- 'item' is a generic type T
- 'selectorList' is of type IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T,string>>>
- 'terms' is of type IEnumerable

After much work, I have gotten to here - but now I am struggling to get it right. I'm missing some fundamental understanding of how I used a ParameterExpression as a Resolved Value when nested.

```
 public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateWhereAnyContainsLambaExpression<T>(IEnumerable<string> terms, params Expression<Func<T, String>>[] selectorList)
    {
        // Create ParameterExpressions
        ParameterExpression qi = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "qi");
        ParameterExpression selector = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Expression<Func<T, String>>), "selector");
        ParameterExpression sTerm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "sTerm");

        // Create ConstantExpressions
        ConstantExpression termsConstant = Expression.Constant(terms);
        ConstantExpression selectorListConstant = Expression.Constant(selectorList);

        // Get MethodInfo
        MethodInfo selectorListAny = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Any").First(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Expression<Func<T, string>>));
        MethodInfo termsAny = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Any").First(m => m.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
        MethodInfo selectorContains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

        // Build the Expression from inside to out....
        //      selector.Contains(sTerm)
        var expSelectorContains = Expression.Call(selector, selectorContains, sTerm);
        //      sTerm => ...expSelectorContains...
        var sTermLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(expSelectorContains, sTerm);
        //      terms.Any(...sTermLambda...)
        var expTermsAny = Expression.Call(termsConstant, termsAny, sTermLambda);
        //      selector => ...expTermsAny...
        var selectorLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Expression<Func<T, string>>, bool>>(expTermsAny, selector);
        //      selectorList.Any(...selectorLambda...)
        var expSelectorListAny = Expression.Call(selectorListConstant, selectorListAny, selectorLambda);
        //      item => ...expSelectorListAny...
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expSelectorListAny, qi);
        
        return lambda;
    }
```

The failure is in the line

```
//      selector.Contains(sTerm)
var expSelectorContains = Expression.Call(selector, selectorContains, sTerm);
```

Where I get the exception

```
System.ArgumentException : Method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' declared on type 'System.String' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[TestObject,System.String]]'
```

Given that sTerm is a parameter expression further up the tree, how do I pass in its resolved representation to the Contains method?

Comment: The problem with using words like "Challenging" in questions is that, by definition, you're not the right person to judge how complex the task at hand is because you don't know how to do it.

Comment: "Complex" might have been better, but honestly I doubt this is anything near what the Roslyn guys had to come up with.

Comment: There's also a part of your question I don't follow: `selectorList` is a `IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T,string>>>`, but then you call `.Contains` on one of its elements. `Func<T,string>` doesn't have a `.Contains` method on it. Can you give an exception of this method being called, so I can see some sample inputs?

Comment: I ended up eating myself with this question. Below I noted that I switched that parameter type to `string` to resolve the issue you point out - `.Contains` isn't a valid method against 'Func<T, string>'. What I'm trying to do is pass in a selector (i.e. `x=>x.MyProperty`) - in fact it's a list of them, and have that be resolved to whatever the objects `MyProperty` value is (it will be `string`). Then use that to call `Contains` against. Does that make sense? I will try to update my question with more context.

Answer (score 2):

So let me clear the confusion I've caused...
I am constructing the lambda `selector.Contains(sTerm)` with the line `var expSelectorContains = Expression.Call(selector, selectorContains, sTerm);`

Now the `selectorContains` MethodInfo is expected to be called against an instance of `string`. However my `selector` is a ParameterExpression of type `Expression<Func<T, String>>`.

I simply matched this to the incoming selectorList variable, where as I should match it to what that resolves to when reduced... which would just be a string.

So the fix was to change

```
ParameterExpression selector = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Expression<Func<T, String>>), "selector");
```

to

```
ParameterExpression selector = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "selector");
```

Doh! My bad. Thank you sincerely for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Enumerable.Any`, and trying to pass in an `Expression<Func<TestObject, string>>`. `Enumerable.Any` takes a `Func<TestObject, string>`, not an `Expression<Func<TestObject, string>>`.

`Queryable.Any` however does take an `Expression<Func<TestObject, string>>`.

So, the answer depends on what you're trying to do. Are you actually trying to call `Enumerable.Any`? In that case you need to compile your `Expression<Func<TestObject, string>>` to an actual `Func<TestObject, string>`, and then you can pass that. Or, as you seem to be working entirely in Expressions (and not compiling them), would `Queryable.Any` be more suitable?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my code to use Queryables, as I think you are correct that it would otherwise fail when getting to the .Any() portion of the expression tree. 

However, I can't get past the first Expression.Call() where I am trying to build the starred section below:

`item => selectorList.Any(selector => terms.Any(sTerm => **selector.Contains(sTerm)**)`

The sTerm is a ParameterExpression, but the exception is letting me know that `string.Contains` expects a string input. The more I look at it, the more it seems like a simple failure of parameter ordering!